# NodeJS Can't set headers error on res.redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect

At the end of an app.post function I am trying to redirect users to a different page (always ends up on the "massChangesSubmitted" page). I keep getting the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`when it hits the line `return res.redirect('/mass_changes')`. The SQL section of the code works great, the only thing that fails is the redirect.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Everything I can find online says the res.redirect line should work. Please help!

**Post code**

```
app.post('/massChangesSubmitted', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).end();

    massChangesSubmitted(function(err){});
    return res.redirect('/mass_changes');
});
```

**massChangesSubmitted code**

```
 function massChangesSubmitted(callback) {
     var sql = 'UPDATE mass_changes SET submitted=1, submitted_datetime=now() WHERE submitted=0'; 
     var dbh = mysql.createConnection(config.db["DB"]) 
     dbh.query(sql, function(err, rows) { 
                     if(err) {
                                     callback(-1); // call callback with error.  
                     } else {
                                     callback(1); // call callback function without error.
                                     console.log("Existing Mass Changes considered submitted")
                     }; 
     dbh.end();
     });
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have closed the connection when you called

```
  res.status(200).end();
```

[res.end()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) ends the connection so you would need to remove that. And also as mentioned in the comments res.status 200 might not be needed of its a res.redirect.

If you really need to send 200 then you can specify any valid https status code in redirect.

```
res.redirect(200, '/mass_changes');
```

Comment: Setting a status of 200 followed by a redirect, which sets its own status (302), is a bit superfluous.

Comment: corrected it. Maybe the OP needs to send 200 so suggesting this alternate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they just want `res.redirect('/mass_changes')`. A redirect with a 200 status isn't a redirect.

Comment: completely removing res.status(200).end() fixed it. Thank you so much!